# What is a good 64-bit NASM assembly reference?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, 64-bit

I have been able to find plenty of 16 and 32-bit NASM assembly references like [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471375233), but the only thing I could find on 64-bit NASM was what was in the small section of the NASM manual [here](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdo11.html). Are there any good sites or books that would have a better explanation of 64-bit assembly (Windows or Linux/Unix) with some good code examples?

Comment: Has NASM ever been updated to be capable of x64? That may be why you cannot find anything.

Comment: I am pretty sure it does. They mention it a bit in the manual.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a great cheat sheet for x86_64 Nasm I found: http://www.cs.uaf.edu/2009/fall/cs301/support/x86_64/index.html.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference concerning the usage of NASM itself (except that you probably want to specify a 64-bit output format), so a 32-bit NASM reference will do fine. Then it's of cource the 64-bit instruction set (and most notably the quite different standard calling convension). AMD has some informative documents here: http://developer.amd.com/documentation/guides/pages/default.aspx